# Dynamic_cast: should be replaced in this case

Tags: c++, state, virtual-functions, dynamic-cast

There is a base class A, which is virtual

```
class A
{
  ~virtual A() = 0;
};
```

and more derived classes B, C, D, E...

```
class B : public A
{
};

class C: public A
{
};
```

and analogously for other classed D, E... We have a list of A pointers

```
std::list <A*> a_list;
```

We remove any element which type is unknown, for example

```
A *a = a_list.front();
```

Base on the type of a pointed object we decide, what to do... There more possibilities how to do that:

**A) dynamic_cast case**

Recasting of a to derived types.

```
if (dynamic_cast <B*> (a))
{
   //do something (but nothing with a)
}

else if (dynamic_cast <C*> (a))
{
    //do other (but nothing with a)
}
```

But the dynamic_cast usage indicates a bad design.

**B) Additional attribute**

Some aditional attribute, for example an object ID is impelemented;

```
class A
{
  virtual ~A() = 0;
  virtual short getID() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
  virtual short getID() {return 1;}
};

class C: public A
{
  virtual short getID() {return 2;}
};
```

So the modified condition

```
switch ( a->getID())
{
   case 1: // do something (but nothing with a)
   case 2: // do other (but nothing with a)
}
```

**A note:**

We do not perform any action directly with the object, but on the basis of its type we do some different computations.

**Questions:**

1) Is it the case, when we should avoid dynamic_cast?

2) is there any prefereable solution (may be different to presented)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think, you can implement [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Item 90 in C++ Coding Standards ([Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)): Avoid **type-switching** (regardless whether you do it with an `if-else` ladder and `dynamic_cast`, or a `switch` statement with `getID()` function). Prefer instead to rely on polymorphism via **virtual functions**

```
class A
{
public:
  ~virtual A() = 0;

  void fun()  // non-virtual
  { 
     // main algorithm here

     // post-processing step
     post_fun();
  }

  virtual void post_fun() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
   virtual void post_fun() { /* bla */ }
};

class C: public A
{
public:
   virtual void post_fun() { /* meow */ }
};

A* a = a_list.front();
a->fun(); // will be resolved at run-time to whatever type a points to
```

The reason is that having an explicit type-switch is hard to maintain and update. If you get a new derived class from `A`, you need to update every place where you loop over types. Instead, the compiler will do that automatically for you if you rely on virtual functions.

Comment: _never_ is pretty strong, but the cases where type switching is appropriate (or necessary) are few and far between.

Comment: @ rhalbersma But I do not want to do any action directly with the analyzed object.. Thus a a virtual function getID() is applicable only to differentiate an object type. I think, that it is a little bit difeferent case.

Comment: @justik That's OK, because the member function `fun()` can do whatever you want, it doesn't have to use any data from `B` or `C`.

Comment: @justik Having different actions in `fun()` depending on the state of the object `a`, is an example of the State Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: @justik Nevertheless, it's a good question and I will upvote it later (have already reached my limit today).

Comment: @ rhalbersma. But this pattern is applicable for simple problems. Let us imagine a very complex scientific calculation having a little difference in the last step depeneding on the object type. Therefore it is very inefficient to write such a function for two different types if functional differencies are small.

Comment: @justik See my updated answer: you can add a non-virtual `fun()` to `A` that does the algorithm (not shown), and a final post-processing step called `post_fun()`. Only this function you then override in derived classes `B` and `C`. The `a->fun()` will then still delegate to calling the correct post-processing step depending on the precise type that `a` points to. So you only need to write small amounts of code, depending on how much difference there is in the last step.

Comment: @justik BTW, this trick of having a non-virtual function call virtual functions inside is called the Template Method pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Comment: @ rhalbersma: That could be a reasonable solution. Preparing my tea I was thinking about the same: to split a computation between type dependent and type independent parts. Thanks for inspiration...

Comment: @ rhalbersma: Thanks. Goede nacht in Utrecht :-)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, when you need to use anything `B`-specific (keeping your naming), you should store `B *` (or `shared_ptr<B>`, rather), instead of `A *`. In all other cases, hide everything behind polymorphism.

Consider following hierarchy:

```
class Animal 
{
public:
    Animal() {}
    virtual ~Animal() = 0;
    virtual void Breathe();
};

class Bird : public Animal
{
public:
    Bird() {}
    virtual ~Bird() {}
    virtual void Breathe() {...}
    virtual void Fly() {...}
};
```

and imagine you're storing `Animal *`s - you shouldn't call `Fly()` now. If you need to call it, then store `Bird *` from the beginning. But all animals must breathe - that's why the function is inherited from base class.

---

To sum it up: if you need to do something `Child`-specific, store pointer to `Child`, not to `Base`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, dynamic cast are perform to get specific type of object to work with them.

```
struct base
{
    virtual void a() = 0;
};

struct foo : base
{
    virtual void a() { ... }
    void specificFooMethod();
};

struct bar : base
{
    virtual void a() { ... }
    void specificBarMethod();
};

base * pBase = ...;
pBase->a(); // no casting required here
if ( foo * p = dynamic_cast<foo*>(pBase) )
{
    p->specificFooMethod();
}
else if ( bar * p = dynamic_cast<bar*>(pBase) )
{
    p->specificBarMethod();
}
```

specific* methods are not virtual and can't be acccessed by base interface without casting. So **dynamic_cast** should be used when you really need specific type of object which have additional functionality/properties that can't be move to abstract layer in base class.